# T-SQL dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a select from a dynamic database in a view, so no declare could be done.

`select * from (select db_table from systables where id = 6)`

The result of `select db_table from systables where id = 6` is my table e.g. table16.

So the above query should be like:
`select * from table16`

I already tried to concat the query to get a varchar but then I get the error at "concat", cause it isn't a object.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) can shed some light

Comment: Why can't the table name be hard coded? Seems like an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @ZoharPeled cause I need then several querys, with this I could just use one and the ids I already have in my query

Comment: Another question - What's the point of having a view that just do `select *`, without even filtering the data? Why not query the table(s) directly?

Comment: I filter it in my view, but first I have to get some data

Comment: you simply can't. dynamic sql may be.

Comment: for views, the only way is to do a big UNION ALL from all your tables and then do some sort of filtering on the outside. This is usually a really bad idea, so i think you should re-think your life decisions that lead to this solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic SQL allowed in Stored Procedures, so you can write one

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getTable
@tableid int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tblname sysname
    DECLARE @sql varchar(500)

    SELECT @tblname = name FROM sys.tables WHERE object_id = @tableid
    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM '+ @tblname
 
    EXEC (@sql)
END
Go

execute getTable 901578250
```

Test code [here](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2022/a993a61d813b08da38c4bc82449fec80/)

Comment: Are you sure of this, is this in the documentation ?

Comment: @GuidoG,  looks yourigth, not only in stored procedures

Comment: Don't use `varchar(64)` for table name. SQL Server use `sysname` for all its identifiers, you should use that data type as well. `sysname` is  functionally equivalent to a non-nullable `nvarchar(128)`

Comment: @ZoharPeled, sure! Thank you for comment. I fixed my answer

Comment: It seems the OP wants to use this on views, have you tested this with views ?

Comment: If you *are* injecting object names you really need to properly quote them (with `QUOTENAME`) and should schema qualify. Not to mentioned,  as well, the bad habit of using `EXEC(@SQL)`. Such statements cannot be parametrised, which promote bad habits that result in security flaws like SQL injection. If you need to run a statement that is within a variable or literal string then use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). Then you can easily parametrise the statement if you need to.